# Is it okay to use a 'hasFetched' with an 'isFetching' flag in redux state?

Tags: redux, state, single-page-application, redux-thunk

I'm new to redux thunk and have been using it to call an action creator that makes a request to an API to see if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged I want to redirect to the login page. I want a loader component to show while the user is still being fetched but also to wait until it has been fetched before either redirecting or showing the page component. This is what my user reducer looks like.

```
//User reducer
export default (state = { isFetching: false, hasFetched: false }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_USER_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, isFetching: true };
        case GET_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
                isFetching: false,
                hasFetched: true
            };
        case GET_USER_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload,
                isFetching: false,
                hasFetched: true
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I can then use the simple function below to check if user state is ready:

```
const isStateReady = state => {
    return !state.isFetching && state.hasFetched;
};
```

I was running into issues without the 'hasFetched' flag as the app would redirect to the login page before the fetch was complete.

Is this an okay way to handle my redux state in my whole application? Are there any other patterns?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your approach. However, maybe you can use part of the state to infer that a user has been fetched? For example, instead of `hasFetched` can you use `user.id`? If there is no user, it would be `null`, if it has fetched it would be a string or number.

Comment: Yeh that makes sense, thanks! I could always change the isStateReady to:
`const isStateReady = state => !state.isFetching && !state.id === undefined;`
And remove the additional work of using the hasFetched flag.